# Late Binding in VB

Tags: vb.net, late-binding

From what I have read so far, late binding is defining a variable as Object and then assigning it to the actual object later which is actually done at run time.  I don't understand the point to that.  Maybe this is the Java in me, but doesn't that limit the functionality to what is just in Object?  It is like saying, "I want the potential of the extra stuff, but I don't want to have access to it."  Is there an actual purpose for late binding in VB, or Java for that matter, that I'm overlooking?

Comment: plugins (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487016/interfaces-and-late-binding-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You need `Option Strict Off` for late binding, and you can then call methods that are not defined on `Object`, which could fail at run time if the actual instance doesn't implement them.

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards.  By using early binding you are limiting yourself to just the members of the type of the variable.  With `Option Strict On`, a variable declared as type `Object` will only allow you access to members of type `Object`, regardless of the type of the actually object it refers to.  With `Option Strict Off`, you can access a member of any name on a variable of type `Object` and the compiler won't complain.  It's only at run time that any type checking is done so, as long as the actual object assigned to the variable has a member with that name, the code will run.

Probably the most common use for late binding is Office Automation.  There are other options now but, in the past, if you referenced an Office library and used the specific types it contained, facilitating early binding, then you were limited to that specific version of Office.  In order to support multiple versions, you had to forgo the reference, declare all your variables as type `Object` and use late binding.  As long as the version of Office present at run time included the specified members on the objects used, the code would run without issue.

By the way, late binding doesn't require using type `Object`, although it is probably the most common.  It just means that the reference is a less derived type than the object and you use a member of the object's type that the reference's type doesn't have, e.g. you use type `Control` and then use a member specific to type `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

What I seen - some early .NET adapters-developers were doing is - they were using late binding instead on interfaces. They would declare two or more types

```
Public Class Handler1
   Public Sub Execute()
       ' do something
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Handler2
   Public Sub Execute()
       ' do something else
   End Sub
End Class
```

And they would stick this thing into `session` object

```
If someting = 1 Then 
    Session("Handler") = New Handler1()
Else
    Session("Handler") = New Handler2()
End If
```

And then, to process something they would do

```
Session("Handler").Execute()
```

There we go. This is not pretty or smart. But that was instead of proper programming like this (Imagine handlers implement `IHandler` interface with method `Execute`)

```
Dim h As IHandler = TryCast(Session("Handler"), IHandler)
If h IsNot Nothing Then
    h.Execute()
End If
```

**Here is where downfall of late binding starts:** In the case of late binding, someone, somewhere, can rename a method Execute and compile code nicely. Release. And only then, at runtime, get a problem.

Late binding was good when we used to deal with `interop` and `COM`. Other than this, it is detrimental.